# Преобразовать результат сложения Double

Tags: java, android

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему результат сложения получается "1.0E-7",
а не "0.0000001" ? И как добиться нужного? Мне надо, чтобы результат был
"0.0000001" .

```
String Lng = "0";
Lng = String.valueOf( Double.parseDouble(Lng) + 0.0000001 );
```

Comment: Попробуй `Lng = String.format("%.7f", Double.parseDouble(Lng) + 0.0000001);`

Comment: Так тоже работает, даже проще, но в проекте ошибку выдавал, а надо было вот так:  Lng = String.format("%.7f", Double.parseDouble(Lng) + 0.0000001).replace(",", ".");

Comment: Не, не надо `replace()`. Тогда лучше так: `Lng = String.format(Locale.US, "%.7f", Double.parseDouble(Lng) + 0.0000001);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.0Е-7 - это тоже самое, что и 0.0000001. Е^7(Е=10) - обозначает кол-во знаков после запятой, т.е. 1 * 10^-7.

UPD: Можно использовать DecimalFormat:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.######");
df.format(yourVariable);
```

Comment: Я это понял, но мне надо результат формата "0.0000001", для записи в файл.. Это координаты, их будут редактировать пользователи..

Comment: @Alex455 обновил ответ.

Comment: Не получается, все равно на выходе "1.0E-7" !    double fff;
String Lng = "0";
fff = Double.parseDouble(Lng) + 0.0000001;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#######");
df.format(fff);
Lng = String.valueOf(fff);

Comment: `Lng = df.format(fff);`